Livewire/Alpine v3 debounce on x-modelable not working
I am trying to debounce the changes in my tiptap editor, via the x-modelable attribute. The plain inputs debounce as expected, while the x-modelable ones do not.
Entangle Version
<div x-data="{value: $wire.entangle('form.body').live}">
    <input class="debounced-input" x-model.debounce="value" type="text"/>
    <div class="editor" wire:ignore x-data="tiptapEditor(value)" x-model="value" x-modelable="markdown">
        <x-tiptap.editor-menu/>
        <div x-ref="editorReference"></div>
    </div>
</div>

wire:model.live.debounce version
<div class="editor" wire:ignore x-data="tiptapEditor($wire.form.body)" wire:model.live.debounce="form.body" x-modelable="markdown">
    <input class="debounced-input" x-model.debounce="markdown" type="text"/>
    <div x-ref="editorReference"></div>
</div>

In both versions, everything works, other than the debounce.
I have included the plain input in each example, which works fully with the debounce.
Here is a working custom debounce example, using watch. Would love to make this simpler though!
<div x-data="{value: $wire.entangle('form.body'), timeout: 0}"
     x-init="$watch('value', (value) => { clearTimeout(timeout); timeout = setTimeout(() => $wire.set('form.body', value), 500) })"
>
    <div class="editor" wire:ignore x-data="tiptapEditor(value)" x-model="value" x-modelable="markdown">
        <x-tiptap.editor-menu/>
        <div x-ref="editorReference"></div>
    </div>
</div>

